# Are Material Components Web and Polymer 2.0 mutually exclusive?

Tags: polymer-2.x

You already know what Polymer is.

I am referring to [Google Material Components Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)

I would like to point out [this specific issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/149) which almost certainly contains the answer, but the light bulb has not went on for me.

`PaperElements` have been around for a while now.  We also now have Polymer 2.0, and I am sure there is some "hybrid mode" but I don't even want to know about that right now.  Assume I will never use any "old" code. I am learning, that is fine.

So that casts doubt onto `PaperElements`.  Are these some kind of old elements which kinda work with Polymer 2.0.... but.... shhh let them die.

I would now expect `PaperElements 2.0` to have a dependency on `material components web`. Of course, the latter is not even Beta and this simply cannot be done right now. But I am just trying to get a handle on the whole picture from a zoomed out perspective and where it is going. I don't have Legacy concerns.

On top of that, whereas the above link mentions frameworks, I don't see anything to do with Polymer, only Angular / Vue etc so I don't even know if Polymer could be called a framework. Perhaps I can just use the web components as intended and custom components have nothing what so ever to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paper-elements` will not be dying anytime soon from what I can tell. As you said, Polymer 2.0 has been released but the `paper-elements` have yet to be upgraded to fully use Polymer 2.0. They have thought, been changed recently so that they will work completely with either Polymer 1.0 or 2.0.

Polymer is *not* a framework. It is a library that helps you to create reusable web components that work like standard HTML elements and follow the [custom elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) specifications.

Polymer is unrelated to `material-components`. From what I can tell, the Material Components library is a library that helps you implement Google's Material Design but does not create "true" web components that meet the W3C standards.

Comment: If I was crazy, could I ignore `paper-elements` and make my own `paper-header` using `material-components`?  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes you could. You could always look into the `app-layout` elements which contains an `app-header` which you can style however you want.